# Choosing more than 1 element from the list

Tags: python, list, numpy, random

I am trying to make a choice for each element in `elements`, and then I am pairing up the element in `elements` list with its preferential choice(one,two or three). The choice is mostly done regarding the probabilities (`weights`) of the elements. The code until here:

```
from numpy.random import choice
elements = ['one', 'two', 'three']
weights = [0.2, 0.3, 0.5]
chosenones= []
for el in elements:
    chosenones.append(choice(elements,p=weights))
tuples = list(zip(elements,chosenones))
```

Yields:

```
[('one', 'two'), ('two', 'two'), ('three', 'two')]
```

What I need is, for each element to make **two** choices instead of one.

The expected output should look like:

```
[('one', 'two'), ('one', 'one'), ('two', 'two'),('two', 'three'), ('three', 'two'), ('three', 'one')]
```

Do you know how to do have this output?

Comment: Those two choices, must they differ or are duplicates allowed? E.g. is `('one', 'one'), ('one', 'one')` a valid sequence in the output result?

Comment: For this you should use the random in the standard library, you are not really using the numpy version.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Duplicates are allowed, however it would be better if there is none. But, definitely allowed

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel Sorry, I did not understand the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need two, just tell `numpy.random.choice()` to pick two values; include the `el` value as a tuple as you loop (no need to use `zip()`):

```
tuples = []
for el in elements:
    for chosen in choice(elements, size=2, replace=False, p=weights):
        tuples.append((el, chosen))
```

or by using a list comprehension:

```
tuples = [(el, chosen) for el in elements
          for chosen in choice(elements, size=2, replace=False, p=weights)]
```

By setting `replace=False`, you get unique values; remove it or set it to `True` explicitly to allow for repetition. See the [`numpy.random.choice()` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html#numpy.random.choice):

> **size** : *int or tuple of ints, optional*
>   Output shape. If the given shape is, e.g., `(m, n, k)`, then `m * n * k` samples are drawn. Default is `None`, in which case a single value is returned.
>
> **replace** : *boolean, optional*
>   Whether the sample is with or without replacement

Demo:

```
>>> from numpy.random import choice
>>> elements = ['one', 'two', 'three']
>>> weights = [0.2, 0.3, 0.5]
>>> tuples = []
>>> for el in elements:
...     for chosen in choice(elements, size=2, replace=False, p=weights):
...         tuples.append((el, chosen))
...
>>> tuples
[('one', 'three'), ('one', 'one'), ('two', 'three'), ('two', 'two'), ('three', 'three'), ('three', 'two')]
>>> [(el, chosen) for el in elements for chosen in choice(elements, size=2, replace=False, p=weights)]
[('one', 'one'), ('one', 'three'), ('two', 'one'), ('two', 'three'), ('three', 'two'), ('three', 'three')]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you accept duplicates, [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) will do the job:

> random.choices(population, weights=None, *, cum_weights=None, k=1)
>
> Return a k sized list of elements chosen from the population with replacement. If the population is empty, raises IndexError.
>
> If a weights sequence is specified, selections are made according to the relative weights.

```
>>> random.choices(['one', 'two', 'three'], weights=[0.2, 0.3, 0.5], k=2)
['one', 'three']
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe: it is weighted; `random.choices()` plural is not `random.choice()` singular. This *does* allow for repeated values (`replace=True` in the `numpy.random.choice()` function).

Comment: @MartijnPieters at the time I wrote the comment it was random.sample...

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah sorry about that, I wrote my first answer a bit quickly...